# Add result set values into Hashmap Map<String,Objct> type

Tags: java, hashmap

I need to add the result set values from MySQL database into Hash map of type
Map .Could you please suggest how to add all values into hash map.

```
 public Map<String,paramObj> fetchThresholdValues( request){
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    BaseDAO db = new BaseDAOImpl();
    paramObj obj = null;
    Map<String, paramObj> oilAndMetalValueMap = new HashMap<String, paramObj>();
    String query = "";
    try {

        conn = db.getConnection();
        query = QueryConstants.GET_PARAMETER_THRESHOLD;
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pstmt.setString(1, request.getPopulationId());
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            obj = new paramObj();
            obj.setParameterName(rs.getString("PARAMETER_NAME"));
            obj.setWatchLowLow(rs.getFloat("WATCH_LOW_LOWER_THRESHOLD"));
            obj.setWatchLowHigh(rs.getFloat("WATCH_LOW_HIGHER_THRESHOLD"));
            obj.setWatchHighLow(rs.getFloat("WATCH_HIGH_LOWER_THRESHOLD"));
            obj.setWatchHighHigh(rs.getFloat("WATCH_HIGH_HIGHER_THRESHOLD"));
            obj.setCautionLowLow(rs.getFloat("CAUTION_LOW_LOWER_THRESHOLD"));
            obj.setCautionLowHigh(rs.getFloat("CAUTION_LOW_HIGHER_THRESHOLD"));
            obj.setCautionHighLow(rs.getFloat("CAUTION_HIGH_LOWER_THRESHOLD"));
            obj.setCautionHighHigh(rs.getFloat("CAUTION_HIGH_HIGHER_THRESHOLD"));
            obj.setWarningLowLow(rs.getFloat("WARNING_LOW_LOWER_THRESHOLD"));

            oilAndMetalValueMap.put(rs.getString("PARAMETER_NAME"), threshold);
        }
```

Comment: You want to put obj as the value in your map?

Comment: i want to put the column PARAMETER_NAME as a key and obj as a value in the map

Comment: @Eklavya yes like that only. So i need to set the key from object  like u did obj.getparameterName and not from getting directly from resultset right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

> For maximum portability, result set columns within each row should be
>   read in left-to-right order, and each column should be read only once.

So you can read only once one column using  `rs.getString`. As you set `PARAMETER_NAME` in `obj` use that when put in map.

```
oilAndMetalValueMap.put(obj.getParameterName(), obj)
```